# Flutter run says '...dependencies could not be established' for the meterial.dart library

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter.io and trying to create my first flutter app according to the following guide

- https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt1/#2

I used terminal command `flutter run` to start my application and then found an error as follows.

```
Your application could not be compiled, because its dependencies could not be established.
The following Dart file:
 ./startup_namer/lib/main.dart
...refers, in an import, to the following library:
  /opt/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/meterial.dart
Unfortunately, that library does not appear to exist on your file system.
```

Couldn't find more details on how to resolve this issue.I am gussing that i should install this library package within my setup.What is the easiest method to install flutter library package from terminal?

Note: i created the app using command `flutter create startup_namer`

Comment: Try `flutter clean` `flutter analyze`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it says `error • Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter/meterial.dart' • lib/main.dart:1:8`.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project with `flutter create my_new_project` and copied the `lib/main.dart` file there? If that doesn't work something with your Flutter installation might be wrong. Please add the output of `flutter doctor -v` to your question.

Comment: What does your `import` statement look like in your .dart file? It should be `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`, but judging by the error message you may have mis-spelled it as meterial.dart

Comment: @DerekLakin you are absolutely correct. I've just mis-spelled the word material.dart.I used vim editor to type the code in and stupidly mis-spelled it.Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the error message you have mis-spelled the package in the import statements m**e**terial.dart

It should be:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

Note: You may run into same error if you were to change the variable "name: myapp" in your pubspec.yaml file with "import 'package:myapp/settings.dart';" as the custom package in the main.dart file as was intended to add "comanyName" text to the app launcher icons. Fix: changed back to "name: myapp" removed the error